# PHP curl maximum execution time using hhvm

Tags: php, api, curl, sails.js

I am trying to download all the data from an api, so I am curling into it and saving the results a json file. But the execution stops and the results are truncated and never finishes.

How can this be remedied. Maybe the maximum execution time in the server of api cannot serve so long so it stops. I think there are more than 10000 results.

Is there a way to download the first 1000, 2nd 1000 results etc. and by the way, the api uses [sails.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails) for their api,

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api.example.com/model';    
$data = array (
  'app_id' => '234567890976',
  'limit' => 100000
);


$fields_string = '';
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');


$url = $url.'?'.$fields_string;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '300000000');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

$response = curl_exec($ch);
print($response);
$file = fopen("results.json", 'w+'); // Create a new file, or overwrite the existing one.
fwrite($file, $response);
fclose($file);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of possible problems might be the cause. Without more details that help understand if the problem is on the client or server, such as with error codes or other info, it's hard to say.

Given that you are calling the API with a URL, what happens when you put your URL into a browser?  If you get a good response in a browser then it seems likely the problem is with your local configuration and not with node/sails.

Here are a few ideas to see if the problem is local, but I'll admit I can't say any one is the right answer because I don't have enough information to do better:

1. Check your `php.ini` settings for [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) and if you are using Apache, the `httpd.conf` [timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) setting. A test using the URL in a browser is a way to see if these settings may help.  If the browser downloads the response fine, start checking things like these settings for reasons your system is prematurely ending things.
2. If you are saving the response to disk and not manipulating the data, you could try removing `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and instead use `CURLOPT_FILE`. This can be more memory efficient and (in my experience) faster if you don't need the data in-memory. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967531/php-curl-writing-to-file) or [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl) on this site for info on how to do this.
3. Check what's in [curl_errno](https://www.php.net/curl_errno) if the script isn't crashing.
4. Related: what is your [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) level? If error reporting is off...why haven't you turned it on as you debug this? If error reporting is on...are you getting any errors?
5. Given the way you are using `foreach` to construct a URL, I have to wonder if you are writing a really huge URL with up to 10,000 items in your query string.  If so, that's a bad approach. In a situation like that, you could consider breaking up the requests into individual queries and then use `curl_multi` or the [Rolling Curl](https://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/source/browse/trunk/?r=16) library that uses `curl_multi` to do the work to queue and execute multiple requests.  (If you are just making a single request and get one gigantic response with tons of detail, this *won't* be useful.)

Good luck.