# curl download from github repo ouputs empty file

Tags: php, git, curl

Looking at [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#download-a-repository-archive-zip) I can download my git repo zip file using:

```
curl -L -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY TOKEN>" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/repos/<MY_GIT_NAME>/<REPO>/zipball/master --output "download.zip"
```

I want to use this curl from within a PHP function:

```
$f = fopen(__DIR__.'/download.zip', 'w+');

$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$repo/zipball/master";

$opt = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FILE => $f,
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opt);

$headers = array(
    "Accept: application/vnd.github+json",
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
    "X-Github-Api-Version: 2022-11-28",
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

The $response is true but the zip file empty. Any ideas?

UPDATE

I am pretty sure the issue is with the curl, as it takes no time at all to execute, whereas a few seconds on the command line. Looking at the curl_getinfo as suggested it looks like I am getting http_code: 403.

I have tried adding:

```
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

and then

```
"User-Agent: $userAgent"
```

into the headers and then get http_code: 302

Comment: Does it work from the command line directly with `curl` or GitHub CLI?

Comment: if you open the downloaded zip file in a text editor such as notepad++, does it show up anything odd that you wouldn't expect (you can perhaps compare it to a copy of the same zip file you download manually yourself from Github)

Comment: @Azeem It works from the command line. The zip folder after the php version though  is 0kb, but should be 100kb.

Comment: @RGriffiths: Right. Looks like you're not writing the response to file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7967561/7670262.

Comment: Check what `curl_getinfo` has to say, especially regarding http_code and download_content_length.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP cURL, read remote file and write contents to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967531/php-curl-read-remote-file-and-write-contents-to-local-file)

Comment: @ADyson Please see the update. I think the issue is more to do with getting the data initially.

Comment: I see. The most likely reason for that 403 then is that the value in `$token` is invalid or expired, or something.

Comment: P.S. If it works from the command-line curl without the user-agent then there should be no reason to need that header in the PHP version. I think at best that might trick github into thinking you're accessing the request from a browser, and that might cause it to try and redirect to you a different, browser-friendly page perhaps (if you're getting a 302, that seems to be what occurred...in that case the response header info ought to also include  Location header telling you where it tried to redirect you)

Comment: @ADyson Good point about the User-Agent. The token is still valid as it still works from the command line. Will keep trying.

Comment: Can we assume you omitted the `$token = ...` line from the PHP you've shown here, just so that you don't publicise the code? `$user` and `$repo` also don't seem to be defined anywhere - same reason? Just double-checking you didn't actually forget them entirely! :-)

Comment: Yes - didn't want to show it. I am using the same at the one in command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so if the request is successful, it will send a `302` redirect as mentioned in the [`docs`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#download-a-repository-archive-zip).

To control this, we will use [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to catch the binary response thrown for the zip file.

At my end, I was forced to add `User-Agent` header too without which I got the request forbidden error. So, added a `User-Agent` as mentioned in the [`docs`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#user-agent-required).

Once the binary data is received, just write that in a `.zip` file name of your choice using `file_put_contents`. Below is the code that works perfectly fine at my end.

**Final code:**

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/repos/some-user/some-repo/zipball/master');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Accept: application/vnd.github+json',
    'Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>',
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28',
    'User-Agent: Awesome-App'
]);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('repo_download.zip', $res);
```

**Note:** If you are unsure about the `ref` branch, just skip it so that the git system takes the default branch. From the [`docs`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#download-a-repository-archive-zip),

> If you omit :ref, the repository’s default branch (usually main) will
> be used.

Comment: That's excellent - thanks. Works perfectly. A follow up question - do you know if it is possible to download a folder from the repo, rather than the whole repo?

Comment: @RGriffiths This [`doc`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-content) is the closest I found. As an alternative, you can download the repo, extract the zip and only copy the folder of your choice to your required destination.

Comment: Cheers. I am currently using your solution to download the whole repo and extract, but I actually only want one folder. I have was looking at your doc ref but couldn't get it to work. Will keep playing around with it. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following line after the `curl_exec()` function:

```php
rewind($f);
```

This will move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file, allowing you to read the downloaded data.

Also, make sure that you have write permissions for the directory where you are trying to save the downloaded file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is not the problem.

Comment: This suggestion implies that the PHP code needs to read the file _twice_. It doesn't.